# No module named _dbus_bindings fedora 34

Tags: dbus, firewalld, sssd

This morning I restarted the computer and I found that System Security Services Daemon(SSSD) and Firewalld services didnt start, so I used systemctl status to view the problem and I got 
**Firewalld:**

```
>systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon... \
>python3[7218]: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/sbin/firewalld' \
>systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE \
>systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. \
>systemd[1]: Failed to start firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
```

**SSSD:**

```
>systemd[1]: sssd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 10. \
>systemd[1]: Stopped System Security Services Daemon. \
>systemd[1]: sssd.service: Start request repeated too quickly. \
>systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. \
>systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
```

Then I tried opening Automatic Bug Reporting tool(ABRT) and it didnt open, so I used terminal to open and found this
[image: output of ABRT in terminal]

I recently updated all apps using "dnf update" and Python 3.9.5(FYI do not know if this was the cause) was one of them.

I tried to run firewalld manually using terminal using the command "firewalld"[image: Output]

So I restarted the computer, and then fsck failed, so the system automatically went to emergency mode, then it cleared some parts, and I rebooted using the terminal in the emergency mode

Firewalld and SSSD still failed and its because of DBus

What should I do now?

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: reinstall is simplest. Rebooting after a failed update seldom ends well.

Comment: Yeah thats often true, I dont know man, I like Fedora 34 and it took time to install, I dont wanna do it all again, but some sites suggested to reinstall Python, and thats a better way but i dont think thats a way, I could wait for them to do some update

Comment: Reinstall is easy.  Finding all the config changes that you've made is a pain.  I once tried checking all of the conf files under /etc into cvs and backing that up, but it got too unwieldly.  Now I just keep a file called admin.txt which lists the software I've added and the changes I've made to system files.  That's backed up with my home directory.   BTW, I wait a couple of weeks to update; I'm still on F33.  Second mouse gets the cheese.

Comment: That was a good idea, but I think I solved it a bit, so I just reinstalled  python3-dbus and updated the system, I think they found out about the error and clarified it, and btw that backup plan is pretty good, but I am a simple guy, I only use python and Blender,I did pip freeze into a file and for Blender, theres not much of addons. The entire thing is backed up either to an NTFS partition or OneDrive, so no worries, it was a mistake from their side, plus I shouldnt have upgraded it to F34 suddenly, although there was not many error in doing so till now

Comment: The answer was simple actually, I just had to update the system, they sort of send some wrong stuff